# Codeigniter dropdown list repeating

Tags: php, sql, laravel, codeigniter, frameworks

There a few schools under HQ and same things goes to franchise. I want to create a dropdown list when I click "Centre" to create new data, it will also create a new data for the all schools who have been group by centre

Here is my **controller**

```
 $this->centre= $this->db->get_where('schools', array('group_by'=>'centre'))->result();
```

And this is **views**

```
       <?php foreach  ($centre as $c) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $c->id; ?>" <?php if(isset($school_id) && $school_id == $c->id){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $c->school_name; ?></option>
        <?php }  ?>
```

[I want to create like this, this is just an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IqGx.png)

Answer (score 0):

`$this->centre` will not get the data to your `view`. You need to pass that data into your view like this:

**Codeigniter 2, 3**

```
$centre= $this->db->get_where('schools', array('group_by'=>'centre'))->result();
$this->load->view('view-file', array('centre' => $centre));
```

**Codeigniter 4**

```
$centre= $this->db->get_where('schools', array('group_by'=>'centre'))->result();
echo view('view-file', array('centre' => $centre));
```

Comment: I tried but didn't get the result that I want. Maybe I should change at view file just to make sure it shows centre only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend

```
    $output = '<select>';
    foreach( $center as $key => $c ) {
        $selected = (isset($school_id) && $school_id === $c->id) ? 'selected="selected"' ? '';

        if( $key === 0 ) {
          $output .= '<option value="">--Select School--</option>';
        }
        $output .= '<option value="'.$c->id.'" '.$selected .'>
            $output .= $c->school_name;
        $output .= '</option>';
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
    echo $output;
```

or using CI form helper

```
$options = array();
$selected = '';

foreach( $center as $key => $c ) {
    $options[$c->id] = $c->school_name;
    $selected = (isset($school_id) && $school_id === $c->id) ? $c->id ? '';
}

echo form_dropdown('select_tag_name', $options, $selected);
```